# Django custom form field layout without manually redoing the whole form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I like Django `form` `render(‘form’: form)` and template `{{ form }}`, but it doesn’t allow you to arrange fields. I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do it, without rendering the whole form manually.

What Django does:

```
First Name
Middle Name
Last Name
```

What I want to do:

```
First Name                 Middle Name
Last Name
```

What makes Django `{{ form }}` so great is that it puts field labels and help text and all that jazz in the right places. Where as manually, you have to put all that in. If there isn’t an easier way, I’m ok with that, but I thought I would at least ask.

Comment: you may want to look into Crispy forms http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ which allows for altering order, layout and adds in some decent bootstrap support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to render individual fields of the form, like this part of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) shows.

Comment: That’s what I thought. I didn’t know if there was something less complex